# How to find the Point in an array of points which is closest to another point

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, c#-4.0

`PolygonPoints` is an array of points used to render a Polygon. I also have a LINQ function that returns the point closest to 0,0.

How can I modify this LINQ funtion **to return the x,y in the PolygonPoints array CLOSEST to the current mouse position**?

LINQ

```
    var PointClosestToZero = PolygonPoints.Aggregate(
    (minPoint, next) =>
         (minPoint.X * minPoint.X + minPoint.Y * minPoint.Y)
         < (next.X * next.X + next.Y * next.Y) ? minPoint : next);
```

Comment: Please clarify: are you asking how to find the closest point to the mouse position while _knowing the mouse position_ (effectively, is this a math question, as you do have a working LINQ query), or while _not knowing the mouse position_ (effectively, the question becomes "How do I obtain the mouse position?"), or both?

Comment: You mean please complicate?

Comment: Which is what I don't know how to do. I also can't help the pun not understanding how it didn't occur to anyone yet to just copy and paste this into a new project. Then visualize it. Then conclude. How can I make the linq function not look for zero but instead my mouse current location? When I feed it my mouse current location it does not work with my mouse current location. Hence the question about mouse current location.

Comment: As a hint, in WPF you can get the difference of two Points by the `-` operator, which gives you a Vector: `var v = p2 - p1`. Vector has a Length property. Task: find the Vector with the smallest Length.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for all the help so far. Hint: I'm not in school. I just have a hobby. In case this is why it almost feels like people just withhold answers on the C# section of StackOverflow.

Comment: Select a new object with point and euclidean distance as properties. https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/DistanceFormula.shtml orderby the distance. Return the first.

Comment: That might not be the best way of doing whatever you want to achieve efficiently though.

Comment: I just wanted to change the LINQ to refer to my mouse current point position and get the closet point to it found in the array of points. Then, I drag, and on mouseup, get this same array index and update it with the mouse location in order to redender a newly reshaped polygon.

Comment: Is it safe to say that we can delete everything after the first paragraph? I think this is just about a few `Point`s, nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What makes this easier is writing smaller functions. Individually they're easier to understand, and then when you put them together it's a little bit easier to read because part of the query contains the name(s) of other functions. It also helps a lot if you use the most descriptive variable names you can think of.

Next, you mentioned that you already have a function to find the point in an array closest to (0, 0). If you want to find the point in an array closest to the mouse, you don't need a different function. Both are the same. You're trying to find the point in an array closest to another point. That point could either be (0,0) or the mouse position.

First, if all of this hinges on calculating the distance between two points, write a function just for that. It will be much easier than including it inline with the query:

```
double DistanceBetweenPoints(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((p2.X - p1.X), 2) + Math.Pow(p2.Y - p1.Y, 2));
}
```

Or with built-in functionality:

```
double DistanceBetweenPoints(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return (p2 - p1).Length;
}
```

Next, if `PolygonPoints` is an array of `Point` and `mousePosition` is a `Point`, then this will give you the point in `PolygonPoints` nearest `mousePosition`:

```
public Point FindClosest(Point[] searchIn, Point compareTo)
{
    return searchIn
        .Select(p => new {point = p, distance = DistanceBetweenPoints(p, compareTo)})
        .OrderBy(distances => distances.distance)
        .First().point;
}
```

The first `Select` produces a set of anonymous objects, each containing a `Point` and its distance from the the comparison point.

The `OrderBy` orders then to find the one with the smallest distance.

`First()` selects the first one (the smallest distance), and `.point` selects just the `Point` from that anonymous object. (`First()` will result in an exception if `searchIn` is empty. You could validate that argument first and throw an `ArgumentException` if the array is empty. That way it's easier to tell what the problem is.)

If you want to find the index of the closest point in the original array, that would be

```
Array.IndexOf(arrayOfPoints, somePoint)
```